# Disappearing question?

Tags: discussion, deleting, moderation

I vaguely remember answering a question along the lines of "What can you get from university that you cannot get elsewhere?". The question didn't seem particularly well expressed and probably a candidate for closure, but I gave a glib answer along the lines of "A university degree.".

In any case, the question disappeared and my activity on the question likewise disappeared from my profile.

I guess a moderator took some action or maybe the OP deleted their own question, but is there any way for me to find out what happened to the question?

(I'm more interested in the system itself rather than the specific question ... I find the precedent of my contributions being able to vanish without any way(?) to find out why just a little disconcerting. Of course, maybe there is a way to find out what happened but I just haven't found it yet.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the question at hand, the user deleted his own question. A deleted question means that the answers aren't visible as well.

The process for finding this info out is to do exactly what you did here - post in meta and a mod can check for you. [Here's a link to the question you're discussing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19700/what-are-things-that-one-can-do-at-university-that-cant-be-done-elsewhere/19701#19701), it's only visible to >10k users (and diamond mods).

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining! I guess it's quite a rare occurrence anyways.

Comment: @badroit Note that the user would not have been able to delete the question if it has had an answer with positive score (or maybe an upvoted one, I forgot the precise details). So while it is possible to have your content disappear without knowing about it, usually this can only happen to the less "good" content.

Comment: I can see it from your link and I don't have 20k.

Comment: @StrongBad >10k, then? I never really understood the difference between 10 and 20 permissions.